# Marcação de Faltas

Tags: vb.net

Boa tarde a todos,

Venho uma vez mais pedir ajuda a todos, pois estou a tentar fazer marcação de Faltas via uma aplicação VB.NET que simula o Processamento de uma empresa completa mas não estou a conseguir.

O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
Dim NumFunc = CStr(CodFunc)
Dim strErro As String = ""
Dim Remuneracao As String = Vencimento
Dim Premio As String = Premios
Dim Ano As Short = Now.Year
Dim Periodo = motor.RecursosHumanos.Funcionarios.DaValorAtributo(NumFunc, "Periodo")
Dim DiasUteis = Convert.ToUInt16(motor.RecursosHumanos.Periodos.DaDiasUteis(Periodo, CShort(Ano), CShort(Now.Month)).ToString())
Dim Flt = DirectCast(e, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs).Value
If Flt = "" Then Flt = "0"
     Dim SimulaFuncionario As RhpBEFuncionario = New RhpBEFuncionario()
     SimulaFuncionario = motor.RecursosHumanos.Funcionarios.Edita(NumFunc)

     Dim RemFunc As RhpBEProcRemuneracao = New RhpBEProcRemuneracao
     If CDbl(Premio) > 0 Then
          RemFunc.Remuneracao = "R301"
          RemFunc.Valor = CDbl(Premio)
     End If

     Dim FltFunc As RhpBEProcFalta = New RhpBEProcFalta
     If CDbl(Flt) > 0 Then
          FltFunc.Falta = "F101"
          FltFunc.Descricao = "Falta"
          FltFunc.Data = Now
          FltFunc.Tempo = CDbl(Flt)
     End If

     Dim DesFunc As RhpBEProcDesconto = New RhpBEProcDesconto
     If CDbl(Flt) > 0 And CDbl(Flt)  1 Then
          DesFunc.Desconto = "D111"
          DesFunc.Descricao = "Perda de Prémio"
          DesFunc.Valor = CDbl(Premio)
     ElseIf CDbl(Flt) = 0 Then
          DesFunc.Desconto = "D111"
          DesFunc.Descricao = "Perda de Prémio"
          DesFunc.Valor = 0
     End If

     Dim SimulaVencimento As RhpBEProcessamento = New RhpBEProcessamento()
     SimulaVencimento.Funcionario = NumFunc
     SimulaVencimento.TipoProcessamento = TipoProc.tpVencimento
     SimulaVencimento.Periodo = Periodo
     SimulaVencimento.Ano = Ano
     SimulaVencimento.NumPeriodoProcessado = CShort(Now.Month)
     SimulaVencimento.DiasUteis = DiasUteis
     SimulaVencimento.DiasProc = DiasUteis - CInt(Flt)
     If CDbl(Premio) > 0 Then
          SimulaVencimento.Remuneracoes.Insere(RemFunc)
     End If
     If CDbl(Flt) > 0 Then
          SimulaVencimento.Faltas.Insere(FltFunc)
          SimulaVencimento.Descontos.Insere(DesFunc)
     End If

     motor.RecursosHumanos.Processamento.InsereLinhaRemuneracao(SimulaVencimento, SimulaFuncionario, Remuneracao, strErro, 1, CDbl(Premio), 1, "AKZ", Ano, CShort(Now.Month))
     motor.RecursosHumanos.Processamento.CalculaProcessamento(SimulaVencimento)
     Dim ValorPrevisto = SimulaVencimento.TotalLiquido()
     ValorPrevisto = ValorPrevisto.ToString("N2"))
     SimulaVencimento = Nothing
```

Tudo funciona (Remunerações e Descontos), mas não estou a conseguir fazer o desconto das Faltas no Vencimento Base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Resolvido no final de muitas horas de estudo.

Deixo aqui a solução para quem possa precisar:

```
Dim NumFunc = CodFunc
Dim strErro As String = ""
Dim Remuneracao As String = Vencimento
Dim Premio As String = Premios
Dim Ano As Short = Now.Year
Dim Periodo = motor.RecursosHumanos.Funcionarios.DaValorAtributo(NumFunc, "Periodo")
Dim DiasUteis = Convert.ToUInt16(motor.RecursosHumanos.Periodos.DaDiasUteis(Periodo, CShort(Ano), CShort(Now.Month)).ToString())
Dim Flt = DirectCast(e, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs).Value
If Flt = "" Then Flt = "0"
Dim DataFlt As String = CStr(Ano) + "-" + CStr(Now.Month) + "-01"
Dim SimulaFuncionario As RhpBEFuncionario = New RhpBEFuncionario()
SimulaFuncionario = motor.RecursosHumanos.Funcionarios.Edita(NumFunc)

Dim RemFunc As RhpBEProcRemuneracao = New RhpBEProcRemuneracao
If CDbl(Premio) > 0 Then
    With RemFunc
        .Remuneracao = "R301"
        .Valor = CDbl(Premio)
    End With
End If

Dim DesFunc As RhpBEProcDesconto = New RhpBEProcDesconto
With DesFunc
    If CDbl(Flt) > 0 And CDbl(Flt)  1 Then
        .Desconto = "D111"
        .Descricao = "Perda de Prémio"
        .Valor = CDbl(Premio)
    ElseIf CDbl(Flt) = 0 Then
        .Desconto = "D111"
        .Descricao = "Perda de Prémio"
        .Valor = 0
    End If
End With

Dim SimulaVencimento As RhpBEProcessamento = New RhpBEProcessamento()
With SimulaVencimento
    .Funcionario = NumFunc
    .TipoProcessamento = TipoProc.tpVencimento
    .Periodo = Periodo
    .Ano = Ano
    .NumPeriodoProcessado = CShort(Now.Month)
    .DiasUteis = DiasUteis
    If CDbl(Premio) > 0 Then
        .Remuneracoes.Insere(RemFunc)
    End If
    If CDbl(Flt) > 0 Then
        .Descontos.Insere(DesFunc)
    End If

    motor.RecursosHumanos.Processamento.InsereLinhaRemuneracao(SimulaVencimento, SimulaFuncionario, Remuneracao, strErro, 1, CDbl(Premios), 1, "AKZ", Ano, CShort(Now.Month))
    motor.RecursosHumanos.Processamento.PreencheDadosRelacionados(SimulaVencimento)
    motor.RecursosHumanos.Processamento.InsereLinhaFalta(SimulaVencimento, SimulaFuncionario, "F101", CDate(DataFlt), CInt(Flt), strErro, OrigemDados.origemVBA)
    motor.RecursosHumanos.Processamento.Calcula(SimulaVencimento)
    Dim ValorPrevisto = .TotalLiquido()
    MsgBox(ValorPrevisto.ToString("N2"))
End With
SimulaVencimento = Nothing
```